# How to display two NSAttributedStrings in different lines in a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I need to display two lines of an attributed string in a UILabel, for example, `theTopMessage` on the first line and `theBottomMessage` on the second line. Both of them are NSAttributedStrings.

I used the following code, but I did not get what I want. `theTopMessage` and `theBottomMessage` are on the same line. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

```
_eventInfoLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_eventInfoLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
_eventInfoLbl.attributedText = info(nsattributed string which holds theTopMessage and theBottomMessage);
[_eventInfoLbl sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Put a newline in the string between the two parts.

Comment: @rmaddy just tried. It works. Thanks very much:)